# Superuser su password reset

Tags: macos, terminal, password, unix

I am using OSX 10.6
I am the admin of my computer, however when I try to login as the super user through my terminal using my admin password, I am denied. Is there anyway to reset the password or find out what my password is?

Comment: Do you mean the root password not your user password?

Answer (score 2):

OS X doesn't set a root password by default, so it's not possible to log in or `su` to root. The preferred way to run commands as root is `sudo`, since that requires your admin password instead of the (nonexistent) root password.

`sudo` works a little different from `su`, as it's really intended to run single commands as root. Generally, you just use `sudo` as a prefix on whatever command you want to run as root (e.g. `sudo cp -R myApplication.app /Applications`). If you want a root shell (as `su` does by default), use `sudo -s`.

I don't recommend setting a root password, but if you do need to do it, you can either run `sudo passwd` or run Directory Utility.app (which is hidden in /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications), clicking the padlock and authenticating as an admin, then choosing Edit menu > Enable Root User.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to recover the root password. You can reset the password by logging in using your normal administrator account, opening the Terminal and issuing the command `sudo passwd`.